# Hola estoy tratando de entrar en mí Smartband Noga Band NG-SB01u no le encuentro la vuelta

Tags: python, django, raspberry

Hola estoy tratando de entrar en mí Smartband Noga Band NG-SB01u no le encuentro la vuelta.

import time
from pygatt.backends import GATTToolBackend

## Crear una instancia de GATTToolBackend

backend = GATTToolBackend()

try:
# Iniciar el backend
backend.start()

```
# Conectar al dispositivo Bluetooth con un tiempo de espera más largo (por ejemplo, 10 segundos)
device = backend.connect("FC:A3:C5:00:00:00", timeout=10.0)

# Leer los datos de pasos
steps = device.char_read_handle(0x21)

# Imprimir los datos de pasos (puedes decodificar los datos según sea necesario)
print("Pasos (datos sin procesar):", steps)

# Si los datos son binarios, puedes decodificarlos a un formato legible, por ejemplo, UTF-8
decoded_steps = steps.decode("utf-8")
print("Pasos (decodificados):", decoded_steps)
```

except Exception as e:
print("Error:", str(e))
finally:
# Detener el backend al finalizar
backend.stop()

Me dan el siguente error:

root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Desktop# python3 -m step_1.py
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)
Error: Timed out connecting to 1A:43:65:87:20:B9 after 10.0 seconds.
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'step_1.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: **path** attribute not found on 'step_1' while trying to find 'step_1.py')

Está conectado a mí Raspberry pi.

Alguien puede darme una mano. O sabe dónde puedo buscar?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.